# Problems understanding the Union functionality of the Union-Find Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, union-find

I am currently doing a course based on algorithms (Coursera). I've come across an algorithm called quick find. The course does have reference to Big O Notation. Despite the fact that I do not have much knowledge of Big O, I have been doing some basic [reading](https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/).

---

***Implementation (Java):***

Initializes the array:

```
public QuickFindUF(int N)
{
    id = new int[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    id[i] = i;
}
```

Checks if two input values are connected:

```
public boolean connected(int p, int q)
{ 
    return id[p] == id[q];
}
```

Union Implementation:

```
public void union(int p, int q)
{
    int pid = id[p];
    int qid = id[q];
    for (int i = 0; i < id.length; i++)
    {
        if (id[i] == pid)
        {
            id[i] = qid;
        }
    }
}
```

The `id` variable is a private instance variable.

---

***My Problem:***

**1)** In the study material it says:

> It takes N<sup>2</sup> array accesses to process a sequence of N union
>   commands on N objects

How can it take N<sup>2</sup> if the `union` method only has a single for loop?

**2)** It also says that the **union** method takes

> at most 2N + 2 array accesses

What does this mean? My speculation is that 2N could mean that the array is accessed twice (line 7 and line 9 of the `union` method). I have no idea what + 2 refers to though.

---

I apologize if I have incorrectly stated something.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your first question is that while it takes (roughly) $N$ array accesses to perform one union operation, it takes (roughly) $N^2$ to perform $N$ of them. This is what is meant by the phrase "a sequence of $N$ union commands".

Regarding your second question, the first two operations are those that initialize pid and qid, and the body of the loop (which runs up to $N$ times) contains two more, one which compares an entry to pid, and another which assigns qid to the same entry.